# USB HDD not recognized

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I have purchased Western Digital 12TB Elements Desktop and took out HDD. Then I connected this HDD to SATA in my computer, kept all partitions, didn´t format HDD anything and moved a lot of files there. After finished, I have connected HDD back to the USB using electronics which was originally used and connected via USB to a PC... To my surprise, my Ubuntu 20.04 is not able to read partitions. Anyone experienced the Has anyone same issue and was able to fix it, anyone? Because this is happening to all of my HDDs which I tested with this method. And again I did not delete, formated, or change any of the partitions on the HDD - there are actually two one with 15MBs and the second the main one.

Anyone can help?

Comment: As written this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. If it did there would be a Ubuntu version in the question.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that there were two drives in the Western Digital 12TB Elements Desktop (one big drive and one small drive)? In that case I thiink that they were synchronized via some custom system, and you made them out of sync.

Comment: Nope, it´s one drive - connected to SATA fully visible to Ubuntu, connected back via electronics to USB not recognized partition (HDD is recognized). Connected to SATA I can see two partitions, one 15MB and second 10GB (approximately don´t know exact number)

Comment: My guess was wrong. I don't know why it does not work, but now I would guess that the drive was set up in some very special way in the USB box with its special electronics. I think only some people at Western Digital can help you. If you are lucky, you can make them send some document describing how to set up your drive to work in the USB box again.

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question if the USB interface ever worked. Some just don't work; if that's the case, try one from a different vendor.

Comment: Yes it worked, I have tested with CrystalMark on Windows, USB worked at the beginning

Comment: Due to the chip used in many USB->SATA adapters, many disks require (re)formatting the HDD used inside the enclosure, and would require (re)formatting the HDD if it's removed and added straight to a user's system. It would have been better to not void the warranty, left the HDD in its original enclosure, and copied/cloned data directly to it.

Comment: Use `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive), re-add desired partitions.

Comment: What format is partition(s)? If NTFS, is it the Windows hibernation flag from Windows fast startup?